Active Choices Parameter usage with Active Choices Reactive Parameter
i am trying to have one active choice parameter that called pg1 as shown below with checkboxes value

and the second Active Choices Reactive Parameter depend on it so whatever i chose in the first parameter it should be removed from the checkbox values in this parameter

so the issue now when i check one box in pg1 it will be removed from pg2 but if i select multiple then pg2 show all. from what i understand it seems the list will be created as ["eht1,eth2"] as single value list always. how i can solve this? i try to slpit it but it wont work should i convert it to string and then split?

I was able to make it working with following changes.
def pg1 = (PG1_PORTS instanceof List) ? PG1_PORTS : PG1_PORTS.split(",").collect{it}
def allPorts =  ["eth1","eth2","eth3","eth4"]
def availablePorts = allPorts - pg1
return availablePorts

If you open Browser Dev Tools(F12) and check the console and network calls going to server when you select PG1_PORTS, its actually sending a String with comma separated selection of values.
So PG1_PORTS.split(",").collect{it} will split string into array and collect the values.


thank you so much and thx for the debugging mechanisim it did not cross my mind. thank you.
